# Sometimes having error Free(): invalid Pointer or realloc(): invalid pointer and application crashes in Linux qt c++

Tags: c++, qt5, report

I have used Lime Report for Reporting tools.
Sometimes application crashes with error `"Free(): invalid Pointer"` or `"realloc(): invalid pointer"` while previewing the report.

Below is the sample code for reference

```
//ReportEngine instance created only once as used to show multiple Reports.

LimeReport::ReportEngine *report = NULL;

    if(report==NULL)
    {
        report = new LimeReport::ReportEngine(this);
    }
    report->loadFromFile(fileName);
    report->previewReport();


Error occurred at the "report->previewReport();" When its called multiple times after open and close the multiple reports.
LimeReport throwing unhandled exception.
```

Comment: It is unclear how the question and the posted code are related to each other. Sometimes this kind of error shows up when you are destroying an already destroyed pointer. Sometimes this shows up when you mix `malloc` with `delete`. There is not enough information to answer definitively. You should research your problem a bit more to narrow down when your pointers are getting freed, and verify that your code is destroying objects correctly.

Comment: Use compiler sanitizers or memory debuggers like Valgrind to help you figure out when and where such problems happen.

Comment: My guess is that you're using something that isn't supposed to be used concurrently from multiple threads...

Comment: Thanks you all for your suggestions. Actually error occurring at report->previewReport(); method. Anybody here who knows about LimeReport?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! I think you should post more code to enable us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This type of memory error almost certainly happens because you did something naughty *somewhere else*.

- You mixed new/malloc with the wrong free/delete for instance. (In
  C++, you should almost never see malloc / free unless you're using a
  C library.)
- Or you did a free/delete, but didn't null the pointer and used it
  again.
- Or you didn't initialize a pointer to NULL (although you should use
  nullptr in modern C++, not NULL).
- Or you overran a buffer. This is why C-style arrays are not good modern C++.

This is just a possible list, but they're all very easy to do, and every experienced programmer has probably done most of them sometime during their career.

Any of these kinds of things can cause problems when you do them, OR they can cause problems LATER. You just don't know. So a problem can appear to be in one place but is caused by something somewhere else.

You said you opened and closed the report. I'd look at that. Does closing the report end it? If so, then you probably want to stop using it.

I would say this: using raw pointers is going to mess you up. Learn to used std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr. See if you can eliminate all references to `*` in your code. It'll save you a LOT of headache.